# create Azure DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, credentials, external-tables

I am trying to create external table. During creation had issue with scoped credential.
Is it possible to create **Azure DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL** with **Active Directory** service account?

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [cred]
WITH IDENTITY = 'Azure AD account',
SECRET = 'password';
GO;
```

Comment: what's the issue? Did you get any error message? Did you login the database with Azure AD admin account?

Comment: i connect to my current database with sa account.

Comment: Msg 46832, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
An error occurred while establishing connection to remote data source: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "chevron.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "chevron.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.

Comment: alter DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [C-DF-WIP]
WITH IDENTITY = 'svc-test@chevron.com@tcowip-dev.database.windows.net',
SECRET = 'password';  
GO

select * from [WIPNCR].[DimWellAnnulus]

Comment: Hi @user12249580, The document said Authentication using Azure Active Directory  is not currently supported. So we can't create Azure DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL with Active Directory service account.

Answer (score 0):

When create the DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL:

The "master_key_password" is a strong password of your choosing used to encrypt the connection credentials. The "username" and "password" should be the username and password used to log in into the Customers database. **Authentication using Azure Active Directory with elastic queries is not currently supported.**

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical#database-scoped-master-key-and-credentials

We can't create Azure DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL with Active Directory service account.